# Binary data input for DyGraphs

Tags: javascript, dygraphs

I have django-based server that sometimes generates large result sets from simulations (saved in HDF5 files). I then send this data to the client to be plotted with DyGraphs. Currently it is sent as JSON, which is fine for small datasets, but very slow for larger ones. I am considering sending the data in binary form, and then receive it as an ArrayBuffer and decoding it into typed arrays. Is there a way to make DyGraphs use typed arrays to display the data?

Comment: Did you end up getting a typed array solution working? I'm looking at doing the same thing since the memory usage of large result sets is pretty crazy with regular Javascript data structures.

Answer (score 0):

You can make dygraphs use whatever data format you like by writing a custom [DataHandler](http://blog.dygraphs.com/2014/12/dygraphs-110.html). The savings may not be as great as you think, though. dygraphs will still make internal copies of your data, whatever the format.

You may also find that JavaScript engines have gotten fast enough that pushing pixels to the canvas is the rate limiting step.